# c# regular expression issue

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to know why, with the following input, the function IsMatches returns false.
What is the problem with my pattern. Thanks a lot.

```
var input = @"/****** Object:  Table [etc_abc]    Script Date: 11/27/2012 13:24:26 ******/";

    public bool IsMatched(string input)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(input, @"/\*+\sObject:\s+Table\s+[\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\\]+\]\.]??(\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\\]+\])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        return match.Success;
    }
```

Comment: what you want to match? the regex you have is not correct.

Comment: Try http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm to debug the regular expression.

Comment: If you escape the opening forward slash (i.e. `\/`), then the regex matches:  `/****** Object:  Table [etc_abc]`

Comment: @hong pei If someone answers your question satisfactorily (and it looks like _nhaldimann_ has) then StackOverflow convention is to mark the answer as accepted. Then your question will show as being answered. Also, if you don't mark answers as accepted then people won't bother answering your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about C# regex in particular, but this part looks suspicious: `[\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\\]+\]\.]??`.

You don't want to treat this as a character class, you probably want to treat it as a group, so use simple parentheses instead of square brackets: `(\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\\]+\]\.)??`

So this might work for you: `@"/\*+\sObject:\s+Table\s+(\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\\]+\]\.)??(\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\\]+\])"`

Comment: A quick check in _Expresso_ shows that this provides a match with the input string.

Comment: acutally, yes. you inspire me! the following will do @"/\*+\sObject:\s+Table\s+(?:\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\\]+\]\.)??(\[[a-zA-Z0-9_\\]+\])"